Cannot connect to gRPC server deployed in Cloud Run
I have a toy hello world gRPC server which I am deploying to Cloud Run which I am having trouble connecting to.

My toy server is (in Go)

package main

import (
  "context"
  "log"
  "net"
  "os"

  pb "my_toy_grpc_server/proto/hello_world"

  "google.golang.org/grpc"
  "google.golang.org/grpc/reflection"
)

// server is used to implement helloworld.GreeterServer.
type server struct {
  pb.UnimplementedGreeterServer
}

func (s *server) SayHello(ctx context.Context, in *pb.HelloRequest) (*pb.HelloReply, error) {
  return &pb.HelloReply{Message: "Hello " + in.Name}, nil
}

func (s *server) SayHelloAgain(ctx context.Context, in *pb.HelloRequest) (*pb.HelloReply, error) {
  return &pb.HelloReply{Message: "Hello again " + in.Name}, nil
}

func main() {


  // Determine port for HTTP service.
  port := os.Getenv("PORT")
  if port == "" {
    port = "8080"
  }

  // Start gRPC server.
  listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":"+port)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error")
  }

  grpcServer := grpc.NewServer()
  pb.RegisterGreeterServer(grpcServer, &server{})
  reflection.Register(grpcServer)
  if err = grpcServer.Serve(listener); err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error")
  }
}


The proto file for the services my server supports is

syntax = "proto3";

package hello_world;

option go_package = "./hello_world";

service Greeter {

  // Sends a greeting
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}

  // Sends another greeting
  rpc SayHelloAgain (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}

}

message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}


The Dockerfile for the container I am going to run my server in is


# Go base image.
FROM golang:1.23.1

# Set the working directory inside the container.
WORKDIR /app

# Install requirements.
COPY ./go.mod ./go.sum ./
RUN go mod download

# Copy the Go code into the container.
COPY . /app

# Build web app executible.
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -o /app/my-toy-grpc-server-exec /app

# Run web app.
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/my-toy-grpc-server-exec"]

Up this point,

My gRPC server runs fine locally. That is, when I run grpcurl -plaintext -d '{"name": "Big Bird"}' localhost:8080 hello_world.Greeter/SayHello, I get the correct response (the correct response is {"message": "Hello Big Bird"}).
When I run a Docker container hosting my service, when I run grpcurl -plaintext -d '{"name": "Big Bird"}' localhost:8080 hello_world.Greeter/SayHello, I get the correct response.


I then make a Docker image out of my code, upload it to GCP Artifacts Registry and run the following gcloud run deploy command

gcloud run deploy my-toy-grpc-server \
--region=northamerica-northeast1 \
--image=<image of my toy grpc server in artifacts registry> \
--platform=managed \
--no-allow-unauthenticated \
--ingress=all \
--use-http2 \
--port=8080 \
--service-account=my-toy-grpc-server@some-domain.com \
--vpc-connector=my-toy-grpc-server-vpc-connector \
--vpc-egress=all-traffic

Now,

When I run grpcurl -H '{Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)}' -d '{"name": "Big Bird"}' url-of-cloud-run-with-my-toy-grpc-server:443 hello_world.Greeter/SayHello (from what I understand, we don't need the -plaintext flag anymore b/c Google takes care of the TLS certs), I get the error Failed to dial target host "url-of-cloud-run-with-my-toy-grpc-server:443": context deadline exceeded.

I think this error is telling me that I am not able to connect to the server?



Now, very oddly (probably only odd to me because I'm not really sure what's going on)

If I first run grpcurl -d '{"name": "Big Bird"}' url-of-cloud-run-with-my-toy-grpc-server:80 hello_world.Greeter/SayHello (i.e. send an HTTP request), I get the error Failed to dial target host "url-of-cloud-run-with-my-toy-grpc-server:80": tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake.
If I then run grpcurl -H '{Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)}' -d '{"name": "Big Bird"}' url-of-cloud-run-with-my-toy-grpc-server:443 hello_world.Greeter/SayHello, it works! I get back {"message": "Hello Big Bird"}) as expected!

If I have omitted a key detail or if something isn't clear, please let me know. Thanks!

Edited to fix some typos.


I'm unable to repro your issue. Your code (mostly) works for me and I'm able to deploy the service and invoke it using gRPCurl without issue (first time). Being unable to repro makes it challenging to provide guidance.

You have an error in your Dockerfile ENTRYPOINT ["/app/my-toy-grpc-server-exec-exec"] the binary is called /my-toy-grpc-server-exec` but I think this is only a typo in your post.

I appreciate that this is a "toy" app and this probably isn't the issue: Your container image is ~1.1GB and the Golang binary is ~13.5MB, I encourage you to consider a multi-stage build and to put the binary in e.g a Distroless image (~17MB).

Thanks @DazWilkin for pointing out the typos and for the tip on Distroless.

I fixed the typos.
I did what you suggested and did a multi-stage build putting the executable in a Distroless image. Unfortunately the error persists :(


Here's my repro of your configuration that doesn't exhibit the issue; I tried this yesterday  and again today creating Projects from scratch.
I'm not using VPC or the serverless connector. Your deployment uses --ingress=all so I'm assuming you're happy with authorized Internet access.
I tweaked your Dockerfile:
FROM docker.io/golang:1.23.1 as build

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./go.mod ./go.sum ./
RUN go mod download

COPY . /app

RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -o /bin/server /app

FROM gcr.io/distroless/static-debian12

COPY --from=build /bin/server /

ENTRYPOINT ["/server"]

Compiled protobuf:
protoc \
--proto_path=${PWD} \
--go_out=${PWD} \
--go-grpc_out=${PWD} \
${PWD}/hello_world.proto

Define environment variables:
BILLING="..."
PROJECT="..."

SERVICES=(
    "run"
    "artifactregistry"
)

REGION="..."

NAME="hello-world"
REPO="..."

IMAGE="${REGION}-docker.pkg.dev/${PROJECT}/${REPO}/${NAME}:v0.0.1"

Deployed:
gcloud projects create ${PROJECT}

gcloud billing projects link ${PROJECT} \
--billing-account=${BILLING}

for SERVICE in "${SERVICES[@]}"
do
  gcloud services enable ${SERVICE}.googleapis.com \
--project=${PROJECT}
done

gcloud artifacts repositories create ${REPO} \
--location=${REGION} \
--repository-format=docker \
--project=${PROJECT}

gcloud auth print-access-token \
| podman login ${REGION}-docker.pkg.dev \
  --username=oauth2accesstoken \
  --password-stdin

podman build \
--tag=${IMAGE} \
--file=${PWD}/Dockerfile \
${PWD}

podman push ${IMAGE}

gcloud run deploy ${NAME} \
--no-allow-unauthenticated \
--region=${REGION} \
--image=${IMAGE} \
--platform=managed \
--ingress=all \
--use-http2 \
--port=8080 \
--project=${PROJECT}

URL=$(
    gcloud run services describe ${NAME} \
    --region=${REGION} \
    --project=${PROJECT} \
    --format="value(status.url)"
)
URL=${URL#https://}

Tested:
TOKEN=$(gcloud auth print-identity-token)

grpcurl \
-H "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" \
-d '{"name":"Freddie"}' \
${URL}:443 \
hello_world.Greeter/SayHello \
| jq -r .

{
  "message": "Hello Freddie"
}


I was able to get it to work using
docker run fullstorydev/grpcurl \
-d '{"name": "Mr. Plow"}' \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)" \
url-of-cloud-run-with-my-toy-grpc-server:443 \
hello_world.Greeter/SayHello

@DazWilkin are you testing on Linux by any chance? Looking at the Dockerfile  for grpcurl, they copy over ca-certificates.crt. I'm on a Mac. I'm wondering if there is a certs problem on my end.

Yes, I'm using Linux. So, if you first test the service using a containerized (i.e. Linux) gRPCurl, it works but if you first test the service using the Mac OS native gRPCurl, you experience the first call failing but subsequent working behavior? If so, then I think you have identified the culprit.

Awesome, thanks so much!
